# How to determine what classes have been loaded from where in JBoss

Tags: java, jboss, classloader

I seem to remember some function in the JMX console which allows you to type in a class name, and see the classloaders which loaded it, and from which resources the class was loaded from.  Unfortunately, I can't seem to find this.  For standalone apps, I've always used the [JWhich](http://www.fullspan.com/proj/jwhich/index.html) tool to get this information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using JBoss 4.2.0 GA, and in the JMX console, I found my component with a type **archive==**.  Going into this MBean shows:

```
MBean Java Class:   org.jboss.mx.loading.HeirarchicalLoaderRepository3
```

Then I just had to invoke:

```
displayClassInfo()
```

with my fully qualified class name.

Answer (score 0):

Try JBoss Profiler or any other profiler.